# representing CRLF using Hex in C#

Tags: c#

How do i represent CRLF using Hex in C#?

Comment: Is there any reason for CRLF specifically?
In most cases Environment.NewLine is a better bet
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Since no one has actually given the answer requested, here it is:

```
 "\x0d\x0a"
```

Answer (score 4):

End-of-Line characters.

For DOS/Windows it's

```
x0d x0a (\r\n)
```

and for *NIX it's

```
x0a (\n)
```

- dos2unix - Convert `x0d x0a` to `x0a` to make it *NIX compatible.
- unix2dos - Convert `x0a` to `x0d x0a` to make it DOS/Win compatible.

Comment: `mac2unix` - Convert `x0a` to `x0d` to make it Classic Macintosh compatible.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why, but it's 0x0d, 0x0a, aka "\r\n".

Comment: @Jonathan: maybe he wants something like ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine) ?